# Trigger to update record on other object

Tags: apex, trigger

I am new to Apex. The scope of the trigger are 2 objects. `Product__c` and `Specific_Product__c`.

There is an after insert trigger on `Product__c` to create a corresponding record on `Specific_Product__c` (only selected fields are being copied over). I have also added the `Id` of the `Product__c` to be passed onto the `Specific_Product__c` so the record on `Specific_Product__c` could potentially be easily referenced against `Product__c`.

I am struggling with writing a trigger that would update the corresponding record on `Specific_Product__c` when an existing record on `Product__c` gets updated. There are no lookup or master-detail relationships between objects.

Is the above scenario possible?

The code is:

```
trigger UpdateSpecificProduct on Product__c (after update) {

    List<Id> idProduct = new List<Id>{};

    for(Product__c p: Trigger.new){
        idProduct.add(p.id);
    }


    Specific_Product__c[] prodToUpdate = [select id 
                                            from Specific_Product__c 
                                            where Specific_Product__c.Product_ID__c IN :idProduct];

    {
        Description__c = p.Description__c,
        Availability__c = p.Availability__c,
    }

    update prodToUpdate;

}
```

Comment: Im struggling to understand the architecture here.  You say 'update the _corresponding_ record on Specific_Product__c when an existing record on Product__c gets updated. _There are no lookup or master-detail relationships between objects_.'  If there is no relationships between them, then what do you mean by _corresponding_?

Comment: Sorry for a confusion. By corresponding I mean the record on Specific_Product__c that contains the Id of a record on Product__c (auto-populated by other trigger).

Comment: I don't follow.  You are carrying the Id of a product on your specific_Product__c record, but its not in a lookup field?

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a lookup on `Specific_Product__c` to `Product__c`? (it could simplify your implementation)

Answer (score 1):

You are quering Specific_Product__c Object with Parent id of Product__c object. But there are no any Relationship between those objects, then how it will query his Parent. First create any M/s or Look-up relationship. Then your trigger will run Properly.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that description and availability are fields on the specific product object.
You will have to add these field references in the query. Also, run a loop on the prodtoUpdate list and crosscheck with the correct product.

I would suggest the below approach.

```
trigger UpdateSpecificProduct on Product__c (after update) {

List<Id> idProduct = new List<Id>{};
Map<Id, Product__c> productDetails = new Map<Id,Product__c>();

for(Product__c p: Trigger.new){
    idProduct.add(p.id);
    productDetails.put(p.id,p);}


Specific_Product__c[] prodToUpdate = [select id,description__c, availability__c, Product_ID__c from Specific_Product__c where Specific_Product__c.Product_ID__c IN :idProduct];
for(Specific_Product__c specific : prodToUpdate){

    specific.Description__c = productDetails.get(specific.product_id__c).Description__c;
    specific.availability__c = productDetails.get(specific.product_id__c).availability__c

}

update prodToUpdate;

}
```

The purpose of the Map here is to avoid a second loop where you would search for the product in the first list.

However, according to me, a better design would be if you store the product as a lookup field (best practice :)).